# How can I order ngFor output based on another array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a data which includes output from 2 shifts with a pastern 8-20 and 20-8.
So I have filtered output using `ngx-pipes` now I need to order Night Shift hours from 20pm to 7am in the morning.

I have an array which specify the correct order of the hours.

```
shiftSelection = [
{
  name: "Day Shift",
  hours: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
},
{
  name: "Night Shift",
  hours: [20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
}]

data = [
    {
      "lineId": 1,
      "hour": 0,
      "input": 9136,
      "output": 8850
    }, 
    ... 
    {
      "lineId": 1,
      "hour": 23,
      "input": 9136,
      "output": 8850,
    }]
```

How can I order ngFor output based on another array?

```
<div *ngFor="let row of data | filterBy: ['hour']: currShift.hours :1 | groupBy: 'lineId' | pairs">
    <span class="group-title">Line {{row[0]}}</span>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cell of row[1]"> 
        <span class="cell" matTooltip="{{cell | json}}">{{cell.output}} 
        </span>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Something like this would be perfect:

```
*ngFor="let cell of row[1] | orderBy: currShift"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lckecp

Comment: if you open StackBlitz I created and change combo box to Night Shift the top row shows hours 20 -7. I would like remainder of the data to be ordered in the same order as currShift variable. If you hover any of the cells you will see the object details and you will see that it goes from 0 to 23.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but day hours and night hours don't have the same number of hours. Where is the array which  you would order them by? Perhaps heavily reduce the example's complexity and show that as a StackBlitz? I'd love to help more.

Comment: Hi Ben, this is actually simplified version. Both shifts have equal number of hours 12. Have a look on the variable shiftSelection, it does contain two objects Day and Night shift. When you select one it assign array hours in the selected object into currShift array. This is array I want to order by. The problem I'm having is if I'm ordering the night shift values ascending it goes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,20,21,22,23, where I want it to be ordered 20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: So you need to order 1 array by another one, i doubt that it's possible with `ngx-pipes` but you can implement your own pipe that fits this purpose. Let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: I think you will need to make a reference array to control the loop that contains your specific hour order `night = [20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` during the loop you can refer to the index to point to the other array's index.

Comment: Hi Ben I already have reference array, it is called currShift. I will try to make a custom pipe as Amir suggested, but never done it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to create a custom pipe. Thanks Amir for suggestion.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'orderByArray' })
export class OrderByArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: Array<Cell>, orderByArray: Array<number>): Array<Cell> {

   var orderedArray = array.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
     return orderByArray.indexOf(a.hour) - orderByArray.indexOf(b.hour);
   });

   return orderedArray;
   }
}
```

and use it that way:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let cell of row[1] | orderByArray: currShift.hours">
```